# Normal Distribution Probability Question

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution

A recent study by the EPA has determined that the amount of contaminants in Minnesota Lakes in parts per million averages 64 ppm with a variance of 17.6. Suppose 35 lakes are randomly selected and sampled. What is the probability that the sample average amount of contaminants is between 64 and 72 ppm?

Answer (score 1):

Let the random variable for the amount of contaminants in parts per million for lake $i$ be $X_i$. From the question we have,
$$X_i \sim N\left(64, 17.6\right).$$
The quantity of interest is the sample average of 35 lakes, call this $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{35}\sum_{i=1}^{35}X_i$. $\bar{X}$ is a sum of normal random variables multiplied by a constant, so it is also a normal random variable.
$$E\left[\bar{X}\right] = E\left[\frac{1}{35}\sum_{i=1}^{35}X_i\right] = \frac{1}{35}\sum_{i=1}^{35}E\left[X_i\right] = \frac{1}{35}\sum_{i=1}^{35}64 = 64,$$
and,
$$Var\left[\bar{X}\right] = Var\left[\frac{1}{35}\sum_{i=1}^{35}X_i\right] =  \frac{1}{35^2}\sum_{i=1}^{35}Var\left[X_i\right] = \frac{1}{35^2} \times 35 \times 17.6 = \frac{17.6}{35}.$$
So,
$$\bar{X} \sim N\left(64,\frac{17.6}{35}\right).$$
Calculating $P(64 < \bar{X} < 72)$ is straightforward from here.

Comment: +1. I am upvoting this answer because it is clear and gets the essential point across -- *and* because it's wrong!  That's actually a good feature in a response to a routine textbook question.  No, there do not appear to be any statistical or mathematical problems; you simply replaced the stated mean of $64$ by $35$ at the outset.  But anyone who reads through your answer will understand that and be able to get the intended answer.